what should unix dev_weight value be set to?
This past week, I was looking for a way to boost server performance despite it having multiple CPUs at 3.3Ghz each.
So I thought, let's increase dev_weight to 512 because documentation states the value of dev_weight means more network packets processed at once. I tried it on my own computer and on the server.
Sometime later, I was unable to access my server at all, and a traceroute confirmed that. Then when I could access it, I checked the logs and noticed it was rebooting every few hours.
So then I changed dev_weight to 16 because I figured I was overloading something at the server end.
When I did the tests on my local computer, my computer fan for the first time in ages turned on like crazy with dev_weight set to 512 when browsing multiple pages on the internet. This didn't happen with dev_weight less than 64.
So what is the limit to how high I can set dev_weight without breaking anything? The reason I ask is because I run web hosting on the server and I'm trying to deliver pages to clients as fast as possible.
dev_weight is a special file in unix found in /proc/sys/net/core folder.
